# How to compute the total return of a fund that had its NAV split in 2?

Tags: mutual-funds

I'm trying to learn how mutual funds work by creating a bunch of small programs. My next target: understanding total returns.

For this, I want to write a program that, when given, for a fund:

- the daily NAVs during a year Y;
- the dividends distributed during same year Y;
- the date and ratio of a NAV split,

computes the total return of said fund for the year Y.

In this case, is the formula below correct?
`total return = (last_nav + div - (first_nav/split_ratio)) / (first_nav/split_ratio)`
And does it matter if the dividend (suppose there's only one) was distributed before or after the split?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using NAV? Typically prices are used to calculate returns instead of the NAV of the fund. If you're using NAV then a "NAV split" would have no bearing on return since it only affects the per-unit price of the fund.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry; by return I meant the performance of the fund, not how much my investment appreciated/depreciated. As for the split's impact, wouldn't a halved NAV make it appear as if the fund lost 50% of its 'value' if it is not taken into consideration?

Comment: No - NAV does not change in a "NAV split". It just doubles the number of units, making the value of each _unit_ half of what is was before the split. It's analogous to a stock split - the total value of the company does not change, it's just split across more shares (or fewer for a reverse split)

Comment: Yes, yes, yes! I see it now, thanks!